# Canon MF8300C series won't print

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have some problem with printer canon MF8300C series. I have downloaded the driver installer from the website. and it seems fine. The installer has install.sh file and I just execute it. My network printer is also detected and it is added to my printer normally. No problem at all. The problem is when I want to print a file. It just not printed. There are no problem appeared at all. I have check the message it is sent to the printer normally.

I have installed this printer for Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04 and I can use it normally. Anyone can help me?

Edit: output of lpstat -t

Edit: I think I remember. I can not print due to the ghostscript and other library version is for 64 bit and my printer can not use 64 bit. I remember I need to install 32 bit version. I forget what they are.

```
scheduler is running
system default destination: Canon_MF8300C_Series
device for Canon_MF8300C_Series: dnssd://Canon%20MF8300C%20Series._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/
Canon_MF8300C_Series accepting requests since 2017年11月17日 11時06分38秒
printer Canon_MF8300C_Series is idle.  enabled since 2017年11月17日 11時06分38秒
```

Comment: could you please add some screenshot or something, there is not much info here

Comment: that's the problem, I don't know what to screenshot. I want to check log file or anything but I don't know which. Any suggestion?

Comment: You could show the output of `lpstat -t` in your terminal to view all Printer information and `lpstat -o ` to show your active jobs

Comment: I wonder if you have "upgraded ...." to 17.10; I ask this because I have seen a number of posts where the early "upgraders" cannot print; where before on 16.04 all was good .. if I were installing the linux driver, I would go here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100270810.html and download the 3.4 that was updated by Canon 8 days ago (9th Nov 2017) .. so commands would be `cd Downloads` and `tar -zxvf  linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken.tar.gz` and `cd  linux-UFRII-drv-v340-uken` and `sudo ./install.sh` and the install script will run;

Comment: i reinstall it. I will add more info in the question if I can find any message or log

Comment: I think you have added a comment in your question; about 32bit; if you use the Canon files, the installer script will check which is the correct version to install ..